# Mod_wsgi from apache 2.2.22 win32 python 2.7.5 64-bit

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Help me get mod_wsgi from apache 2.2.22 win32 python 2.7.5 64-bit. The compile this binary file for me is not possible. Thank you for understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you download the binaries from the site linked from the mod_wsgi site?

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2#Windows_Binary_Downloads

Comment: Because this is mixed system: apache x86 and python x64.

Comment: The rule is you must use all 32 bit or all 64 bit for Apache/Python/mod_wsgi. You cannot mix them, Windows simply doesn't allow you to mix the different binary architecture types. Now if you are running 64 bit Windows, you can still run 32 bit binaries on it, but those components still must all be 32 bit and what you can download should work fine so long as you select the right ones. You should not need to recompile anything.

Comment: Taking the x64 system, we embarrass yourself using the x32 software. (I try to configure MapServer + TileCache, but I have fundamental mistakes). Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

> The compile this binary file for me is not possible.

Why impossible?
I had the same issue when upgrade python version from 2.6 to 2.7.5 on debian squeezy. To make it work need compile (or find) mod_wsgi extension for current python version.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm not saying it's impossible, I just have no possibility to compile, so I ask, maybe someone did it and can provide me already compiled file.